# how to remove tab name in URL in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

In my DNN project the tab URL being formed is like this

```
http://localhost:57425/test_15sept/EN/tabid/83/ctl/Tab/action/edit/returntabid/64/Default.aspx
```

and i want to remove the `EN` from the URL, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a 3rd party url rewriting solution like iFinity UrlMaster (http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Url_Master_DNN_SEO_Urls) to do this or switch to non-friendly urls (host -> host settings). This will put your site in this format though, ?tabid=XX&param=1&param=2